# od command displays nothing on macOs while running

Tags: macos, catalina

I am running the command `od -b users.avro` to see the content but it outputs nothing.

Comment: The only time I've seen `od` not output anything when passed a _file_  is if the _file_ is 0 bytes in size. There of course may be other reasons but I've one had no output for the reason mentioned. Do you get the sane results with other _files_ you pass to `od`?

Comment: Alternatively, try `xxd -g 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The command `od -b users.avro` will output nothing if the file is empty. What does `file users.avro` output? If it outputs `users.avro: empty` then you have your answer.

Comment: The file do have content and i can run the `cat` command to see the binary content